# Python counting multiple substrings

Tags: python, optimization, refactoring

I am trying to count the number of times letters show up in a string, so i'm using the count() function which is working fine, however using multiple count() functions seems tedious since i'm trying to count 10+ letters.

```
def printer_error(s):
 #errorLetters = ('r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')
 errorRate = s.count('o') + s.count('p') + s.count('q')


 print(errorRate)
 return 

printer_error('aaaxbbbbyyhwawiwjjjwwm')
```

My first attempt was  s.count(errorLetters)  but that failed because the count() function can't take tuples or lists.

the current code is giving me the result I want but I still have to concatenate the rest of those commented out letters in the errorLetters variable, is there another way to do this that doesn't involve making 20+ concatenations?

Comment: The errorRate variable listed currently doesn't count anything because I wanted to keep it alphabetical, but I texted it beforehand with 'w' and 'y' and got the result I wanted.

Comment: It's a shame we can't downvote on comments.  @ewcz proposal is not good, it's needlessly inefficient to use `s.count` inside the loop.

Comment: @wim fair enough ;) `sum([1 if c in errorLetters else 0 for c in s])`

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this only requires to iterate `s` once, i.e. O(n).

Standard library `collections` module provides a `Counter` object that will be useful and efficient:

```
>>> s = 'aaaxbbbbyyhwawiwjjjwwm'
>>> errorLetters = ('r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter(s)
>>> sum(counts[k] for k in errorLetters)
8
```

Comment: There are a ton of useful libraries this is works great